# Help Recognizing Characters on a Vase (Characters Identified: 錦山)

Tags: character-identification

I have a vase

[image]

with these characters on the bottom

[image]

and would be very grateful if someone could tell me what they mean.

Comment: The title has been edited with the characters you are looking for. Not sure if there's much point in keeping this open any longer now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the name for a mountain... 錦 means bright and 山 means mountain.
A search on the internet also tells me that 錦山 is a name for different places. Places like a county in South Korea or administrative districts in certain towns in China.

Comment: Or it might be the artist's signature.